# Android, how to get information on which activity is currently showing (in foregorund)?

Tags: android, focus, android-activity

I wonder if there is a way to get information on which activity currently has focus (is in the foreground)? I am using instrumentation and I would like to know which activity is currently running in the application that I am testing against.

Thanks

Comment: I've been looking for a solution, but haven't found anything yet... :(

Comment: wouldn't solo.getCurrentActivity().getLocalClassName(); do the job?

Comment: This question was asked long before Robotium existed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **Robotium** 
*'a open-source test framework created to make automatic black-box testing of Android applications significantly faster and easier than what is possible with Android instrumentation tests out-of-the-box.'*

Homepage: 
http://www.robotium.org/
Source:
http://github.com/jayway/robotium

*Please note that the Robotium project is maintained by the company I work for*