# Can an Android application know when another Android application is running?

Tags: android

Assume Applications Foo an Eggs are on the same Android device.  It's possible for either application to get a list of all applications on the device.  Is it possible for one application to know if another application has run and for how long?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278895/how-to-check-current-running-applications-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a list of installed applications by using the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).
Code from [here](http://androidboss.com/getting-list-of-installed-applications-in-android/):

```
public class AppList extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

To see the currently running apps, you can use the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html).

Answer (score 1):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327985/android-find-how-much-network-traffic-other-apps-generate/5332600#5332600) explains how you can achieve that functionality in a generic way.

This [post](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/138412-android-20-list-of-running-applications/) and this [one](http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2011/05/way-to-check-whether-application-is.html) have snippets of an Activity that lists the running applications, using `ActivityManager`'s `getRunningAppProcesses()`.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run) explains how to get a list of all installed applications and then to choose one to run.

Comment: It should be added that you'll need to add a permission to your manifest to use getRunningTasks() or getRecentTasks(). android.permission.GET_TASKS to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html).