# Measure Time Spent on Android Applications

Tags: android

I am new to android. In my application, i want to track for how much time other applications (which are installed on device) are used (in foreground).

Is it possible? If yes then how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064137/can-an-android-application-know-when-another-android-application-is-running) link may help you.

Comment: click the word this... it's a hyperlink :)

Answer (score 4):

First thing , that's required to be known here is what are the applications that are running in the foreground :

You can detect currently foreground/background application with `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()` call.

So, it will look something like ::

```
  class findForeGroundProcesses extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

      @Override
      protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
        return isAppOnForeground(context);
      }

      private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) {
          return false;
        }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
          if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }

    // Now  you call this like:
    boolean foreground = new findForeGroundProcesses().execute(context).get();
```

You can probably check this out as well : [Determining foreground/background processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service).

To measure the time taken by a process to run its due course , you can use this method :

```
getElapsedCpuTime()
```

Refer this [article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#getElapsedCpuTime%28%29) .

Answer (score 3):

I think that the only way to do this it's by using a background service and continuously searching which app is in foreground (it's possible by using ActivityManager).

But this solution is costly in battery