# Android : How I track time spent on android applications

Tags: android, android-activity, usage-statistics

I need to build a android app that checks how much time you spend on a selected app X, if the consumed time is more than a preset value - the app will show a message every time you run X and X will exit.

As an example, you set in our app that the maximum allowed time for WhatsApp is 20 minutes per day. If you consumed the 20 minutes and you try to open WhatsApp - you will get a message and WhatsApp task will be closed.

Is it possible? If yes then how?

Please let me know with some sample code.

Comment: Sample code? Sorry. Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: And yes your question "track time spent on an app" has this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397784/measure-time-spent-on-android-applications

Comment: Yes it is possible. Set the start time on the onCreate Method of the application or on the main activity. Or start a timer. I will not add sample code. Why i should do you work?

Comment: @Zelldon: He is asking if he can track the usage of another app. I have gave him the link I found on SO after a simple search. :D

Comment: @Rohit5k2 : 

I am new to android.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics

I used this sample, but it return "Last time used" not usage time, Please advise.

Comment: Did you try the link i gave? See this answer and try to implement it http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398407/2936153

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UsageStats` to get the spent time for any app. Check this link - 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html#getTotalTimeInForeground()