# How to find time spent on specific app?

Tags: android

> How to Get the Time spent on an specific application using **packagename** in Android Programmatically?

After doing google I found this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32825854/6333971) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31097599/6333971) but I didn't get any proper solution.

Does any one know how to I get that time for all android version?

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16397784/6333971) but I don't want to do background service. **When user back to my app I just want to know that does user used that app for given time or not.**

Comment: what you have done and what actually? Please give more description about your question

Comment: are you want to get recent applications which are used ?

Comment: recent app but using specific **packagename**

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267482/android-programmatically-open-recent-apps-dialog

Comment: @vivekmahajan Sir I'm newbie in android how to find In which specific app user spent given time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do two things for achieve that.

> **1. Start timer when user left your activity and goes to another app.**
>
> **2. call background service using below code**

```
private void check()     
{
    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
            this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
    {
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("specific pacakgename here")) {
           
            //check time here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be tough for me but let me try

Comment: can you give any Github or project source link? Thanks

Comment: what you mean check the time here?

Answer (score 1):

The way I mentioned below is a very efficient way to get the total spent time of an app by a user in android. First of all you need to a custom **ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** which is responsible to trigger out when the application began to start and when stop. You need to just register the **ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** to your application instance. This will also care about if any user pauses the app so you don't need to think about it.The custom **ActivityLifecycleCallbacks**  class is -

```
public class ApplicationTimeSpentTracker implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    private int activityReferences = 0;
    private boolean isActivityChangingConfigurations = false;
    private long startingTime;
    private long stopTime;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        if (++activityReferences == 1 && !isActivityChangingConfigurations) {

            // App enters foreground
            startingTime=System.currentTimeMillis()/1000; //This is the starting time when the app began to start
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
        isActivityChangingConfigurations = activity.isChangingConfigurations();
        if (--activityReferences == 0 && !isActivityChangingConfigurations) {

            // App enters background
            stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;//This is the ending time when the app is stopped 

            long totalSpentTime= stopTime-startTime; //This is the total spent time of the app in foreground
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }
}
```

Finally you need to register the callback to your application instance in **MainActivity** like this -

```
    activity.getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ApplicationTimeSpentTracker());
```

Here is my [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-get-total-time-spent-android-programmatically-emon/) if you need details

Comment: I wanted to know spend time of other apps like digital wellbeing.