# How to check if a user is currently running and using an app on android?

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio

Is it possible to use android to detect if a certain app on an android phone is open on the screen. For example, checking to see if the user is currently using his/her photo's app. Most of the questions I've read so far are checking the whether a certain BACKGROUND app is running; I'm trying to figure out whether I can check if a certain app is currently open and running on the screen. So using my app (which would be running in the background) to detect whether an app, for example the photos app, is open and being used by the user.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064137/can-an-android-application-know-when-another-android-application-is-running

Comment: @DaniIvanov that's not exactly what I'm looking for because I'm wondering whether it's possible to see if an app is currently running on the screen, not in the background.

Comment: @FireSun No, that's not what I'm asking for. I'm not asking for background apps. I'm asking whether an app is currently open on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActivityManager am =(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo task = tasks.get(0); // current task
ComponentName rootActivity = task.baseActivity;


String currentPackageName = rootActivity.getPackageName();
if(currentPackageName.equals("com.sec.android.gallery3d")) {
     //Do whatever here
}
```

Use currentPackageName to see if it is the application you want.

For More Info, Look Here: [Android: How can I get current opened application name on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118721/android-how-can-i-get-current-opened-application-name-on-screen)

EDIT:
Also, you should add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this should work!