# Is there a way to detect if Chrome Browser is being used in Incognito mode for API<20?

Tags: android, google-chrome

In Android, Is there a way to determine when Chrome is being used in Incognito mode?

Sorry for no code, not sure what is a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been asked and answered : [Detect anonymous / incognito browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379317/detect-anonymous-incognito-browsing)

In short :  you cannot know it for sure thanks to an API or anything, but you can try to guess, from the history for example.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Will mark this as answer in ~7mins